# How do I remove selected endlines with sed?

Tags: sed

I'm trying to remove endlines for all lines in my file where the endline splits two equal signs

ie:

```
1
a=
=b
2
```

to

```
1
a==b
2
```

I have

```
sed -i.bak -e 's/=\n    =//g' fileName
```

however, it doesn't seem to make any changes to my file. Is my script correct?

Answer (score 2):

Try this. It saves the whole file content in pattern space and the removes all newline characters between equal signs.

```
sed -i.bak -e ':a ; $! { N; b a }; s/=\n=/==/g' fileName
```

It yields:

```
1
a==b
2
```

Comment: @blueberryfields: My info: `GNU sed version 4.2.1` in Linux. Any error?

Comment: sed on mac os x 10.7.5, don't think it has a version number. No errors :(

Comment: @blueberryfields: Sorry. I can't help with that. It seems that newlines are treated different in `OS X`, as I can read [here](http://superuser.com/questions/307165/newlines-in-sed-on-mac-os-x). I don't know if it could be related to this answer.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '$!N;s/=\n=/==/;P;D' file
```

or

```
sed -e '$!N' -e 's/='$"\n"'=/==/' -e 'P' -e 'D' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Different seds on different OSs treat newlines in different ways. The most portable way to specify a newline in sed is to use backslash before a return:

```
sed -e 's/=\
=//g' file
```

BUT that's not going to work for you until you invoke some other magic sed characters to slurp up multiple lines into a buffer, etc....

Just use awk:

```
$ cat file
1
a=
=b
2
$ awk '{printf "%s%s", $0, (/=$/ ? "" : "\n")}' file
1
a==b
2
```

Just prints the current line followed by nothing if the current line ends in an "=" or a newline otherwise. Couldn't be simpler and it's highly portable....

Oh, and if you want to change your original file, that's just:

```
awk '{printf "%s%s", $0, (/=$/ ? "" : "\n")}' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```